# Parse XML Node With C#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

My XML that is returned is in this format

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <CITY>Hull</CITY>
    <STATE>GA</STATE>
    <ZIP>30646</ZIP>
    <AREA_CODE>706</AREA_CODE>
    <TIME_ZONE>E</TIME_ZONE>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I want to extract the value contained in `TIME_ZONE`.  This data is being returned by this syntax `System.Xml.XmlNode result`  How can I parse an `XmlNode` to find `TIME_ZONE`?

I have tried the below - but it gives me an error of

> cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'string'

**Syntax Attempted**

```
System.Xml.XmlNode result = uszipcode.GetInfoByZIP(zip);
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(result);
```

Comment: You are mixing the order of your commands. An `XDocument` should be parsed before queried.

Comment: @zx485 - I thought that I was passing the zip into the wsdl file then going to parse the xml structure in my post that is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get string representation of XML part referenced by an `XmlNode` from `OuterXml` property :

```
System.Xml.XmlNode result = uszipcode.GetInfoByZIP(zip);
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(result.OuterXml);
String timeZone = (string)xml.Descendants("TIME_ZONE").First();
```

Or, you can find the target element from `XmlNode` directly using [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
System.Xml.XmlNode result = uszipcode.GetInfoByZIP(zip);
String timeZone = xml.SelectSingleNode(".//TIME_ZONE").InnerText;
```

Comment: The SIngleNode approach looks cleaner, but I do not understand it.  Googling it now so I can learn something new with XML, thank you for te response

Comment: You're welcome. Just an aside, nothing special with `SelectSingleNode`, it simply accepts *XPath expression* as string. The powerful part here is the XPath. You can use XPath to query XML using various criteria. You can learn XPath separately from C#. Use XPath tester to play around while you learn it. I mostly use [xpathtestrer](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) and [xpatheval](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a typo.  The error is due to passing an XMLNode when a string is expected for XmlDocument.Parse.  Try this:

```
XmlNode result = uszipcode.Get...
string myNodeValue = result.OutterXml; // this will give you XML node tree you need as a string..
XDocument xml = XDocument.parse(mynodeValue);
```

Comment: Changing my syntax to - string result = uszipcode.GetInfoByZIP(zip); - produces an error of Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'string'

Comment: Then the method already returns an xmlnode. No need to pass result to xmldoc. Just get the value from it eg result.InnerText

Comment: that is my issue, I do not know how to "get the value from it"

Comment: Yes, the method would return a `System.Xml.XmlNode`, but that is of no use at all, because the `Parse` method of the [`XDocument Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) requires a `String` as an argument.